# Pyinstaller: GUI can transfer to .exe but it show ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I use pyinstaller and let my GUI code bundle to a .exe suceessfully. But when I run the .exe, it show

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
File "EL_GUI.py", line 56, in EL_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

My GUI  code include

```
eclf = pickle.load(open('EL_model.sav', 'rb'))
```

This file I open is that I saved Ensemble Learning model parameter

If I add `import sklearn` in GUI code,then it will show

```
File "c:\users\charlie\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 253, in visit
return visitor(node)
File "c:\users\charlie\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 257, in generic_visit
for field, value in iter_fields(node):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please avoid posting code as pictures.